# WiX Edit v0.7.5.0 - Check for .NET Framework Version > 3.5

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I am using Visual Studio Express for Desktop 2013, because I am using the express version I have decided to use WiX to build a simple installer.

I am using WiX Edit v0.7.5.0 and have WiX Toolset v3.8 installed.

I have successfully built an msi that works, but would now like to add a .NET Framework check into the equation.

I am still very new to using WiX and I have followed the steps in this how to guide and I can get a msi built which includes a check for the .NET Framework Version 3.5:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/check_for_dotnet.html

As soon as I try to check for the .NET Framework Version 4.0 or above I encounter errors.

I have simply amended the PropertyRef and Condition as follows:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL" />
<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again."><![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL]]></Condition>
```

When I then run the Build MSI Setup Package I get the following in my Results Panel:

```
    ----- Starting C:\Program Files (x86)\WixEdit\wix-3.0.5419.0\candle.exe -nologo "C:\Users\GT\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WiX\Temp.wxs" -out "C:\Users\GT\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WiX\Temp.wixobj"  -ext WixUIExtension  -ext WixNetFxExtension  at 05/09/2014 14:34:12

    Temp.wxs

    Done in: 358 ms

    ----- Starting C:\Program Files (x86)\WixEdit\wix-3.0.5419.0\light.exe -nologo "C:\Users\GT\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WiX\Temp.wixobj" -out "C:\Users\GT\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WiX\Temp.msi"  -ext WixUIExtension  -ext WixNetFxExtension  at 05/09/2014 14:34:12

    C:\Users\GT\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WiX\Temp.wxs(39) : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:NETFRAMEWORK40FULL' in section 'Product:F0989A9C-638B-4924-8BB1-6556A546E2AE'.

----- Finished

Error in light
```

I have done quite a bit of searching to try and resolve this problem and have came across several articles which seem to agree with what I have done, alas I am still getting the same error message shown above.

Am I missing something quite simple here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Extension dlls from the WiX Toolset itself instead of those packaged by WiXEdit will ensure that light.exe is using the most current dlls.

For Example:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WixEdit\wix-3.0.5419.0\light.exe -nologo "C:\Users\GT\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WiX\Temp.wixobj" -out "C:\Users\GT\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WiX\Temp.msi"  -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\WixUIExtension.dll" -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\WixNetFxExtension.dll"
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested by trying to run the light.exe path from a command promt, but I now get a new error message of error LGHT0010: The WixLocalization/@Culture attribute was not found; it is required.

Comment: assuming you are developing for the US add -cultures:en-us to your command line

Comment: Same error now received as with WiXEdit: error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'Property:NETFRAMEWORK40FULL' in section 'Product:F0989A9C-638B-4924-8BB1-6556A546E2AE'

Comment: In Visual Studio have you added a reference in your WiX project to the WiXNetFxExtension? Also verify that the WixNetFxExtension.dll is in the path that you are sending light.exe, it's possible that WixEdit puts it somewhere else.

Comment: I only have Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop so I don't believe I can create a WiX Project, this is why I am using WiXEdit, everything works fine when I check for .NET 3.5, just not for newer versions. I appreciate all the help you have given so far.

Comment: candle.exe, light.exe, WixUIExtension.dll and WixNetFxExtension.dll can all be found in this folder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WixEdit\wix-3.0.5419.0" which is what I have used in my command line attempts at running the required code.

Comment: I looked up WiXEdit and it looks like it's not been updated in 3 years, perhaps there's an issue with Wix3.8 and it, you might look at Sharp Develop as I believe that is active and has WiX support.

Comment: Ah! Using the command line I have now managed to get it working by pointing to the dll's in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wix Toolset v3.8\bin\" folder, rather than the ones in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\WixEdit\wix-3.0.5419.0\" folder.

Comment: I updated my answer to incorporate using the Toolkit dlls instead of those provided by WixEdit